# Solving general initial value problem $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x'}, t)=\mathbf{0}$

Tags: ode, rootfinding

The common form of initial value problem that can be solved using ODE integrator is
$$
\mathbf{x'}=\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}, t)
$$
where $\mathbf{x'}=\partial\mathbf{x}/\partial t$. The initial conditions $\mathbf{x}(t=0)$ are given. There has been a lot of prewritten solver that can be used to solve the equation above (e.g. `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`) that typically uses Runge-Kutta algorithms.

However, if I change the form above into a more general one, i.e.
$$
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x'}, t)=\mathbf{0},
$$
there is no algorithm I can find that can solve it (assuming it contains sufficient information to be solved). Please note that the first form above is just a specific case of the second form, i.e.
$$
\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{x'}, t)=\mathbf{x'}-\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{x}, t)=\mathbf{0}.
$$

Is there any algorithm available out there that can solve the general form of initial value problem above?
Any reference to literatures or codes are appreciated!

Comment: The general form of the ODE you show is referred to as the implicit form. If you search based on this term, you will find a number of solvers that can handle this form. For example, here is a high-quality solver that accepts implicit form: https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/sundials/ida

Comment: $f(x,x',t)=0$ can easily also be a DAE system, and what its normal form is depends on the differential index. Some general solvers also cover index 1 and 2 DAE, for higher index one needs to transform the equation system.